# Grails Resources: Bundle multiple modules to single file

Tags: grails, resources, grails-2.0

I have module `A`, `B` and `A_and_B` that depends on `A` and `B`. When I use module `A_and_B` Grails Resources plugin generates 2 js/css files (one from module `A`, one from module `B`). How can I obtain single css/js file? I can use same `defaultBundle` value for all modules but then modules `A` and `B` will be broken

Answer (score 0):

Class `CommonResources` contains closures with common resources + util method

```
class CommonResources {
static a = {
    resource url:'js/a.js'
    resource url:'css/a.css'
} as Closure

static b = {
    resource url: 'js/b.js'
    resource url: 'css/b.css'
}

static loadResourcesOn(resources, object) {
    resources.delegate = object
    resources.call(object)
}
}
```

We our resources configure using following structure

```
modules = {
a {
    CommonResources.loadResourcesOn(CommonResources.a, delegate)
    CommonResources.loadResourcesOn(CommonResources.b, delegate)
}

b {
    CommonResources.loadResourcesOn(CommonResources.b, delegate)
}
}
```